# knockout.js and disable custom binding

Tags: knockout.js, ko-custom-binding

I would like to bind disabled and css within a custom binding instead of using JQuery to assign a class and disabled it.  Can you do this within a custom binding without doing `$(element).attr('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');`

```
data_bind="enabled: classroomId(), css: { 'disabled' : !classroomId() }"


data_bind="disable: { !classroomId() }

ko.bindingHandlers.disable = {
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var disabled = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());


                 // Disable and Add Class to Button or Anchor Tag

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knockout now contains a `disable` binding that mirrors the enabled one, you can either use jQuery or call the existing css and disabled bindings ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/Yvvm4/1/)):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myDisabled = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        ko.bindingHandlers.css.update(element, function() {return { disabled: value }; });
        ko.bindingHandlers.disable.update(element, valueAccessor);
    }
};
```

Html:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: name, myDisabled: !enabled()"/>
```

Comment: Would of never knew you could access default custom bindings like that, thanks!